# здравствуйте, как сделать так чтобы 2 блока отображались в ряд , а не в столбик , пробовал inline-block для обоих элементов, не помогло

Tags: html, css

[![

```css
body {
  background-color: #4d525e;
}

<!-- основной блок-->.container {
  background-color: #fff;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 165px 198px 0px 198px;
  height: 800px;
  max-width: 1170px;
  width: 800px;
  border-radius: 20px;
  padding: 109px 0px 0px 82px;
}

.container__items {
  font-family: monospace;
}

.inform {
  margin: 0;
}

.bfr {
  margin: 0;
  padding-bottom: 15px;
}

.lorum {
  text-align: justify;
  max-width: 510px;
}

.buttons {
  margin: 40px 0px 0px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

.btn {
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  width: 530px;
  height: 86px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  letter-spacing: 2px;
  font-family: inherit;
  background-color: #fff;
  border: 3px solid rgba(230, 250, 250, 1);
}

<!-- 2 блок -->.ending__smth {
  display: inline-block;
}

.rer {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: green;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  <title>Site</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="container__items">
      <h3 class="bfr">lorem ipsum doler</h3>
      <h1 class="inform">Become a member</h1>
      <p class="lorum">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam</p>
    </div>

    <div class="buttons">
      <button class="btn googler">sign up using google+</button><br>
      <button class="btn facebook">sign up using facebook</button><br>
      <button class="btn twitter">sign up using twitter</button>
    </div>


  </div>

  <div class="ending__smth">
    <p class="writing">you can also sign in using emailadress</p>
    <a class="rer" href="#"> use your email</a>
  </div>


</body>
```

][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jWkPx.png)][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jWkPx.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Не стоит использовать inline-block и float.
Используете Css Flex, прочитайте про это.

Оберните .container и .ending_smith и добавьте `display: flex;` (или на body)

Comment: да, спасибо, с flex сработало, но вопрос все же есть, почему inline-block все-таки не расположил их в ряд?где-то читал что тег <a> может повлиять на это, это правда?

Comment: Не расположил рядо наверно из за того что ширина экрана меньше суммы ширины двух блоков. Тег a используйте только по назначению.  Если вам подошёл ответ примите ответ,поставьте галочку

Answer (score 0):

вот примеры:

1
display: inline-block;
2
float: left;